# Execute a command in a new terminal window

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm on ubuntu 17.04, and I'm trying to execute some commands in sequence, so I have written this shell script:

```
#!


sudo java -jar ~/Desktop/PlugtestServer.jar
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
sudo node httpServer.js
```

The problem is that after the first command, it execute PlugtestServer and then stop on it, because it is a server and continue to execute it. There is a command in order to automatically open a new terminal and execute PlutestServer in it?

Answer (score 2):

There is way to open a new terminal window and execute command in it using gnome-terminal
The sample format for command is:

```
gnome-terminal -e "command you want to execute"

gnome-terminal -e "./your-script.sh arg1 arg2"
```

Hope that helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Your script stays on the first command showing output, you can make the shell move on by adding "&" to the end of your lines. However this might still not do what you want, if you want PlugTestServer to remain running when you log out. For that you should include "nohup" which will keep the command running while piping output to a file.
So, an example:

```
#!/bin/sh
nohup java -jar ~/Desktop/PlugtestServer.jar > plugtest.out & #Pipes output to plugtest.out, use /dev/null if you don't care about  output.
/opt/lampp/lampp start
node httpServer.js
```

Notice I removed sudo from the script. It's generally better to invoke the script with "sudo" unless you have specific reason to, at the very least it simplifies the commands.

I'm not sure if your second and third command "fork" or "block", so add "nohup" and "&" if you need to.